# Do small-resolution resource/texture packs really have an effect on performance?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen 8x8 and smaller resource/texture packs that claim to increase ingame fps (frames per second), but then other people comment saying that there is no difference. Who is right?

EDIT: I just found this similar thread on the Minecraft Forums: [Do 8x8 Resource Packs make Minecraft Faster? (1.7.2)](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/2094378-do-8x8-resource-packs-make-minecraft-faster-172/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Neither and both. Confusing?

Here's the deal: Minecraft uses quite a deal of processing power, both with the CPU and the GPU. Texture packs are handed by the GPU.

Now consider the following: Loading an 8x8 texture is 1/4 of the load of loading a 16x16 texture (that is the default size). However (and here's the catch), despite the less work, you would only notice any difference if the GPU was *bottlenecking* the process. In other words, if you weren't running at top graphical performance, you *may* see some small difference.

The reasoning here is also valid for HD texture packs: the bigger the texture, the more load the GPU is subject to and your performance will drop accordingly.